# Declare and initialize elements in a matrix Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I find it challenging to initialize elements in a matrix (2d array). I know how to declare a 2d array and prompt user for input and then print it, but if I have a 2 d array with 5 rows and I in every row want that column 0 is articleNumber, column 1 is price and column 2 is amount I fail to connect the userinput with the "variable".

The task I want to practice and understand is described this way.

"create a matrix that contains information about 5 articles. Each article (row) must contain the article number, price, and number. Show how to declare, assign and print the contents of the matrix (all columns for all rows)."

I would be very thankful if someone could help me out with the initializing. This is what I did so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDArrays 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner (System.in); // create the scanner object
        
        // Variables
        
        int r = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int [][] twodArray; // declare the 2d array object
        
        // prompt user for input
        
        System.out.print("How many rows do you want? ");
        
        r=s1.nextInt();  
        
        System.out.print("How many columns do you want? ");
        
        c=s1.nextInt(); 
        
        
        
        twodArray = new int [r][c]; // the 2d array size is defined by user
        
        
        // insert value.
        
        
        System.out.println("Please insert values ");
        
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++) 
        {
            
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++) 
            {
                twodArray[i][j]=s1.nextInt();
                
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            
        }
        
        
        // Prints out values
        
        System.out.println("Here is what you entered");
        
        for(int i=0; i<r; i++) 
        {
            
            for(int j=0; j<c; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(twodArray[i][j] + " "+" ");
                
            }
            
            System.out.println();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far? This way we can see where exactly you are going wrong and what your mistake is.

Comment: I tried to edit my post. I don't have a mistake in this code but I'm not sure how to connect number, price and amount :)

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean with "connect number, price and amount". I also really don't understand why you let the user enter how many rows and columns you want when the assignment is asking for fixed values: 5 rows (1 for each item) and 3 columns for each attribute. And with this fixed design you know that `twodArray[0][0]` is the article number for the first item, `twodArray[0][1]` is the price for the first item and `twodArray[0][2]` if the number.  Not sure what "connecting" of "variables" you want here.

Comment: I could do it fixed - but like the flexibility when testing :). I need to assign the values entered to number, price and amount in that order since I later want to maybe remove or insert new articles. But I guess it's not the way to do? 

Can I maybe say something like final int articlenumber_column = 0, price = 1 and amount 2? then promtp user to type twodArray[i][articlenumber_column] ?

Comment: I mean, yes you could do that. But `final int articlenumber_column = 0` would still be hardcoded in your program. So I really see no real advantage over just using `0` directly except maybe a slightly better readable code. I should probably note that if the assignment didn't ask for using a 2D array my first advice would have been to not use one. Because storing data like this is really not how you would do things in a real program. If you wanted to save data for an item you would create your own custom class `Item` that has fields for each attribute and then use that class.

Comment: I see what you mean. Makes sense :-) - yes I have to do 2d array. I will practice this for an assignment where I have to make a cashregister, where I can insert more rows if the user wants to insert more articles than the length of the array. Also I will have to remove an item, print out sales history and all stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to ask how many rows and columns the user wants to enter because those are fixed values specified by your assignment: You need 5 rows - 1 for each item, and 3 columns for the 3 attributes each item has.

You first declare your array as

```
int[][] items = new int[5][3];
```

And you could then just initialize/fill that array with a simple loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter Data for item " +i);
    System.out.println("Enter article number:");
    items[i][0] = s1.nextInt();  
    System.out.println("Enter price:");
    items[i][1] = s1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    items[i][2] = s1.nextInt();  
}
```

Of course you could still use a nested loop to fill the columns of each item. But with a fixed value of 3 I really see no reason to do that.

Edit:

It should be noted that using a 2D array like this is a really bad choice for a data structure. Your assignment specifically asks for that but in reality you would be much better of creating a class for  the Item:

```
public class Item {
    private int articleNumber;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int number;
    
    public Item() {
    }
    
    public int getArticleNumber() {
        return articleNumber;        
    }
    
    public void setArticleNumber(int articleNumber) {
        this.articleNumber = articleNumber;        
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

And then you would use a List or Array of that custom class

```
final List<Item> itemList= new ArrayList<>();
```

And using your getters/setters to set the attributes of each item

```
final Item newItem = new Item();
itemList.add(newItem);
    
System.out.println("Enter article number:");
newItem.setArticleNumber(s1.nextInt());  
// ... etc pp. for the other attributes
```

Comment: That helped a lot :-)  Can I ask why you say items[i]= new int [3] inside the loop? tried to run the code with and without it, and it gives me same result when I print it in console :)

Comment: You are right, that line was redundant and not needed